# Is there a list of verses from the Bible which the Joseph Smith Translation has modified/restored?

Tags: bible, lds, reference-request, jst

Rather than busting out a KJV and a JST and comparing them verse by verse I am lazily hoping that there is, somewhere, a list which has already been generated providing all of the verses from the Bible  which the JST has modified or allegedly 'restored'?

Comment: To clarify - The introduction to the Joseph Smith translation indicates that its purpose is to restore truth. It's purpose is not to restore the autographical texts of the Bible. To be just a touch humorous while also making this point, let us consider...the autographical texts of the Bible were written in Hebrew, Aramaic, and Greek. The Joseph Smith translation is in English, and is therefore not a verbatim copy of the autographs. So "redacted" might not be the right word to use in the question.

Comment: Closely related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/83970/51818

Comment: @HoldToTheRod The edits are appreciated.  I had only used the terms redacted and restored based upon other LDS answers and comments.

Comment: @HoldToTheRod Forgive me but I missed this thread from 3 months ago. You said, "To clarify - The introduction to the Joseph Smith translation indicates that its purpose is to restore truth." Perhaps you can give a list of the truths that had to be restored?

Comment: Hi @Mr.Bond - many such lists have been created -- if you're interested in reading an article, see an example [here](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/2006/10/plain-and-precious-truths-restored?lang=eng)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing I have found online to a complete listing of restored or retranslated passages is this online interactive comparison viewer at [ScriptureToolbox.com](https://www.scripturetoolbox.com/html/ic/index.html), which lets you see from the table of contents which chapters have retranslated portions, and highlights the differences in context.

Print editions of books do exist that show side-by-side comparisons:

[Complete Joseph Smith Translation of the New Testament (Overdrive.com)](https://byu.overdrive.com/media/1675147) - borrowable online

[Joseph Smith's New Translation of the Bible (Amazon.com)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0830900322) - not an affiliate link

There are manuscripts of the new translation available at [JosephSmithPapers.com](https://www.josephsmithpapers.org/the-papers/revelations-and-translations/jsppr5).

You could also download a text form of the KJV, perform a diff with the JST, and store the edits with verse references to a file.
I might do this myself when I have a minute; I have worked in plain text Scripture files before but had not yet located a plain text file of the JST in an easily digestible format.

Selections are published as an appendix to the Standard Works of the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, and can be found here:

https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/jst?lang=eng

The rights to some portions of the JST belong to the Community of Christ, they have an online edition of it (they call it the Inspired Version or IV), including a browser with side-by-side comparisons:
https://centerplace.org/

Some more background and resources can be found here:
https://rsc.byu.edu/joseph-smith-translation/joseph-smiths-translation-bible

Note that Joseph Smith's translation was never officially "finished".

Answer (score 4):

I personally think a focused list of some of the most significant differences is more helpful than a comprehensive list for the whole Bible. Below, differences by Joseph Smith are bolded:

> "But to him that seeketh not to be justified by the law of works, but believeth on him who justifieth **not** the ungodly, his faith is counted for righteousness," Joseph Smith, Romans 4:5

Paul wrote that God *does* justify the ungodly.

> "**In the beginning was the gospel preached through the Son. And the gospel was the word, and the word was with the Son, and the Son was with God, and the Son was of God.**"  Joseph Smith, John 1:1

This is entirely different than what John 1:1 really says.

> "**For unto such hath God promised his Spirit.** And they who worship him must worship in spirit and in truth." Joseph Smith,John 4:26

Jesus instead said, "God is Spirit." The Joseph Smith version aligns well with the LDS doctrine that God is not a Spirit and instead has a body of flesh and bone.

> "And David said unto Nathan, I have sinned against the Lord. And Nathan said unto David, The Lord also hath **not** put away thy sin, that thou shalt not die." Joseph Smith, 2 Samuel 12:13

2 Samuel actually records that God *has* put away David's sin.

> Joseph Smith added about a dozen verses to the end of Genesis 50. This includes a new verse 33 which says, **"And that seer will I bless, and they that seek to destroy him shall be confounded; for this promise I give unto you; for I will remember you from generation to generation; and his name shall be called Joseph, and it shall be after the name of his father; and he shall be like unto you; for the thing which the Lord shall bring forth by his hand shall bring my people unto salvation."**

If you are unsure that Joseph Smith added himself into Genesis 50, in the Book of Mormon, it says in 2 Nephi 3:14-15
“And thus prophesied Joseph, saying: Behold, that seer will the Lord bless; and they that seek to destroy him shall be confounded; for this promise, which I have obtained of the Lord, of the fruit of my loins, shall be fulfilled.  Behold, I am sure of the fulfilling of this promise; And his name shall be called after me; **and it shall be after the name of his father.  And he shall be like unto me**; for the thing, which the Lord shall bring forth by his hand, by the power of the Lord shall bring my people unto salvation.” (bold added to emphasize similar phrases)

Finally, it is commonly stated that Joseph Smith did not complete his translation, but as of March 24, 2024, the [official LDS stance](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/history/topics/joseph-smith-translation-of-the-bible?lang=eng) is that “Once finished with the New Testament, Joseph picked up where he left off in Genesis and completed his work on the entire project by July 1833.” So the Joseph Smith translation actually is complete.

On that note, another reference I found online is that it says in the official History of the Church, Volume 1, page 324, “I completed the translation and review of the New Testament, on the 2nd of February, 1833 and sealed it up no more to be opened till it arrived in Zion,”

Finally, here is the entire [Joseph Smith translation online](https://www.centerplace.org/hs/iv/), as well as other LDS Scriptures, in case you want to read more.

Comment: Very nice answer. Welcome to stack exchange Christianity.  Take the tour. It'll help. +1

Comment: @MikeBorden Thank you, and I forgot about the tour since I was busy when the site told me about it, but I just took the tour.