# What is the Roman Catholic position on the validity of the marriage between an infertile man and infertile woman?

Tags: catholicism, sin, marriage, sexuality

What is the Roman Catholic position on the validity of the marriage between an infertile man and infertile woman? Also, from this standpoint, what is the difference between a marriage in which both partners are opposing sexes but infertile and a marriage in which both partners are the same sex?

Comment: Can you scope your question a little to a specific denomination? This question, I believe, is asking for personal opinion. That, or it's a "truth" question.

Comment: As anonymous says you've got to scope this a bit more. Christianity is not monolithic and there may not be one specific reason for this. You'll need to tighten this up to either speak to a specific group or doctrine. Essentially, this question shows a lack of any attempt to learn the answer before asking.

Comment: @waxeagle My question is now more cleared up and is more specific to one denomination.

Comment: @Anonymous: Isn't this version of the question a duplicate of [How does a Roman Catholic reconcile a preference for purely procreative sex with the Song of Solomon?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5594/how-does-a-roman-catholic-reconcile-a-preference-for-purely-procreative-sex-with?rq=1)

Comment: Your secondary question about same-sex marriage falsely assumes that the reason why the Church considers it a sin is *because* they cannot conceive.

Comment: in addition to the comment from @StevenDoggart, you've also *presumed* the man and woman ***KNOW*** they are infertile, and choose to get married **in spite**. You've also implicitly disallowed those beyond the years of child-bearing (eg a couple in their 60s or 70s) from marrying

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are asking about the validity of a marriage between people who cannot conceive children. The position is summed up in [this paper](http://www.catholiceducation.org/articles/religion/re0155.html). To summarize:

> Infertility does not prevent a person from validly entering into marriage. The Code of Canon Law affirms, **“Sterility neither prohibits nor invalidates marriage”** (No. 1084.3). Appreciating the suffering of an infertile couple, the Catechism states, “Spouses to whom God has not granted children can nevertheless have a conjugal life full of meaning, in both human and Christian terms. Their marriage can radiate a fruitfulness of charity, of hospitality, and of sacrifice” (No. 1654). In this case, a couple can consummate the marriage, but they just cannot conceive children.

Your last point, about marriage between partners of the same sex, is an entirely different question and I suggest you ask it separately.

Comment: I would add that the couple should still have an openness to children because doctors can be wrong and God can work miracles.

Comment: Indeed it is the requirement for *openness* to children that people often confuse with a requirement to *have* children in Catholicism.  Just because you are open to children doesn't mean God will necessarily cause you to have them.